# How to limit input character from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I have released my first website in RoR and I get under attacked ...

My website is a simple board where you can post article with title and content.

I have limited the number of character in the title to 150 like this in my view

```
<%= form.text_field :title, :maxlength => 150, class: 'title_input' %>
```

and like this in the controler

```
def create
  if (params[:article][:title].length > 150)
      render 'new'
  end
  @article = Article.new(params[:id])
  if @article.save
    redirect_to article_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seems to work the user is spamming me with 75 000 characters title and they are all emojis

I'm using recaptcha for making the spam less important but 10 post like this is enough to make my app down.

I cannot ban him because he keeps using new IP and change it so fast.

Do you have any idea how can I block this ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I solved it by using a validator in my model like this

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 1..100 }
```

Thanks to Sampat

Comment: use validations - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length

Comment: I addd the validations, it seems to work now and to be the solution.
Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the codes in to your model. it will restrict maximum limits

```js
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 500,
    too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default rails behavior, the params you're using should be empty, as the correct hash should be something like `params[:article][:title]`, or if you're using strong params: `article_params[:title]`.

Have you actually checked if `params[:title]` is containing said information? I'd suggest you debug how the information is sent to the server, and then adding the corresponding restriction to the correct param key

Comment: Yes it's a mistake when I copied my code, I used `params[:article][:title]`. Is it normal that when I use rails console I can create an article with 500 characters ?